Is it possible to create a multi color radial gradient using xml vector drawables?
I've seen how this is done for linear gradients, like this answer: can we make multi color gradient in xml for android background?
Every time I try this for a radial gradient the viewport fails to render, so I thought maybe my syntax was wrong since using the aapt:attr tag does not give any autocomplete suggestions. I would deeply appreciate any help please.

Yes, it's possible to create a vector drawable with multi-color radial gradient.
The easiest way is probably to import an existing vector asset (such as SVG)
using the Vector Studio tool.
Here's an example drawable:
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
  <path android:pathData="M50,50m-50,0a50,50 0,1 1,100 0a50,50 0,1 1,-100 0">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:centerX="50"
          android:centerY="50"
          android:gradientRadius="50"
          android:type="radial">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
        <item android:offset="0.33" android:color="#FF008000"/>
        <item android:offset="0.66" android:color="#FF0000FF"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
</vector>

